# Understanding the Bentley-Ottman Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

This is the code:

```
  Initialize event queue EQ = all segment endpoints;
    Sort EQ by increasing x and y;
    Initialize sweep line SL to be empty;
    Initialize output intersection list IL to be empty;

    While (EQ is nonempty) {
        Let E = the next event from EQ;
        If (E is a left endpoint) {
            Let segE = E's segment;
            Add segE to SL;
            Let segA = the segment Above segE in SL;
            Let segB = the segment Below segE in SL;
            If (I = Intersect( segE with segA) exists) 
                Insert I into EQ;
            If (I = Intersect( segE with segB) exists) 
                Insert I into EQ;
        }
        Else If (E is a right endpoint) {
            Let segE = E's segment;
            Let segA = the segment Above segE in SL;
            Let segB = the segment Below segE in SL;
            Delete segE from SL;
            If (I = Intersect( segA with segB) exists) 
                If (I is not in EQ already) 
                    Insert I into EQ;
        }
        Else {  // E is an intersection event
            Add E’s intersect point to the output list IL;
            Let segE1 above segE2 be E's intersecting segments in SL;
            Swap their positions so that segE2 is now above segE1;
            Let segA = the segment above segE2 in SL;
            Let segB = the segment below segE1 in SL;
            If (I = Intersect(segE2 with segA) exists)
                If (I is not in EQ already) 
                    Insert I into EQ;
            If (I = Intersect(segE1 with segB) exists)
                If (I is not in EQ already) 
                    Insert I into EQ;
        }
        remove E from EQ;
    }
    return IL;
}
```

I have a few questions for example in the left endpoint case 
what if a or b doesnt exist? If a exist and be doesnt should we check the second if or none of them?

In the first iterations SL is mostly empty therfore most of the points at beginning are removed without being used What is the point of that?

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` don't exist, then of course no intersection with them is possible. If only one exists, then only that one can be checked for intersection.

I'm not sure what you mean about points being "removed without being used". All events in the event queue are important, either because they're upcoming intersections or because they set up potential upcoming intersections by keeping the sweep line up-to-date.

Finally, it's Bentley-Ottmann, not Bentley-Ottoman.

Comment: Lets look at the first Segment that is taken from the EQ , at that time nothing exsits in SL thefore there is nothing above it or below and there is no intersection to be checked... And at the end the point will simply be removed

Comment: The point is removed, but `SL` now contains a segment. `EQ` is not a list of potential intersections; it is a list of things that need to be done for the algorithm to work properly.